# difference in using the import and from * import statement

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

When I install PIL http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/ on 32 bit python, I can use `import Image` and then use the Image library inside PIL. However, for the 64 bit python, I downloaded http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/. However, when I use `import Image`, it gives me error, "No Module named Image". However, I can use `from PIL import Image`.
Why is that I can use import Image directly in one instance and not in another?

Comment: Different packagings; PIL has traditionally been broken when it comes to that. That's why [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.0.0) was started.

Comment: Have they got pillow working/testing on 32-bit yet? Last time I checked, only Windows (and only certain versions) were supported… which meant you had to use `pillow` on 64-bit, `PIL` on 32-bit, and double the amount of `try`/`import` logic…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're different libraries. Or, to be specific, they're different packaging of the same library.

PIL is notorious for these sort of issues. Just use [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.0.0) instead.

Answer (score 2):

You want to install [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.0.0) instead.

It comes in both 32 and 64 bit variants for Windows, and has fixed long-standing issues with the original PIL library.

The PIL library has [long been broken](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/image-sig/2010-August/006480.html) when it comes to packaging. Pillow was started as a fork to fix these issues once and for all, and version 2.0.0 added Python 3 support (with a [grant from the Python Software Foundation](http://aclark.net/blog/2013/03/15/the-story-of-pillow/)).